# replace value of element in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to replace value of `<ResourceId>` element. If I delete everything before 
`<VectorLayerDefinition>` and after this element everything works fine, but I have a lot of these xml files and I can't delete anything from it manually. Any suggestions?

Here the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="sdf:FeatureClass1">
    <ns0:FeatureSource xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" rdf:resource="fsd://1" />
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="sdf:FeatureClass1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/LayerDefinitionResource" />
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="sdf:FeatureClass1">
    <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">FeatureClass1</ns0:name>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="sdf:FeatureClass1">
    <ns0:isURL xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">no</ns0:isURL>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="sdf:FeatureClass1">
    <ns0:description xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">
    </ns0:description>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="sdf:FeatureClass1">
    <ns0:LayerDefinitionResourceStream xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">
      <LayerDefinition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="LayerDefinition-2.4.0.xsd" version="2.4.0">
        <VectorLayerDefinition>
          <ResourceId>Library://SDF_1.FeatureSource</ResourceId>
          <FeatureName>sdf:FeatureClass1</FeatureName>
          <FeatureNameType>FeatureClass</FeatureNameType>
          <Geometry>Geometry</Geometry>  
    </VectorLayerDefinition>
      </LayerDefinition>
    </ns0:LayerDefinitionResourceStream>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="fsd://1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/FeatureSourceResource" />
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="fsd://1">
    <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">1</ns0:name>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="fsd://1">
    <ns0:isURL xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">no</ns0:isURL>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="fsd://1">
    <ns0:description xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">
    </ns0:description>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="fsd://1">
    <ns0:FeatureSourceResourceStream xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">    </ns0:FeatureSourceResourceStream>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="LayerSchema">
    <ns0:version xmlns:ns0="http://www.autodesk.com/gis/resource/definitions/" xml:lang="en" rdf:parseType="Literal">1</ns0:version>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Here my code:

```
public void Main()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Repositories\Library\Content\Layers\FeatureClass1.LayerDefinition");
    string str = doc.Element("VectorLatyerDefinition").Element("ResourceId").Value;
    doc.Element("VectorLayerDefinition").Element("ResourceId").Value = "SomeValue";
    doc.Save(@"D:\Repositories\Library\Content\Layers\FeatureClass1.LayerDefinition");
}
```

But it works after I "cleaned" xml file

Comment: **How** do you delete or add elements in your file? Basically doing so manually is a really bad idea. Instead let serializers do their job, whioch is **reading and writing** files.

Comment: Indeed - I'd do this by loading an `XDocument`, manipulating it, then saving it again. Without seeing your code, it's going to be hard to help you further.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  I'm just open file and delete manually everything exepts `<VectorLayerDefinition>` element. I ve tried to do my job using linq but it didnt work out cuz I cant pass through first node.

Comment: Element only looks in current level. You want Descendants which will recurse down tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml liinq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication80
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement resourceId = doc.Descendants("ResourceId").FirstOrDefault();
            resourceId.SetValue("//SDF_2.FeatureSource");

        }
    }
}
```